# Слайдер как у яндекса

Tags: javascript, html, css

помогите найти решение по слайдеру.

Задача сделать слайдер как у яндекса, [посмотреть пример](https://m.market.yandex.ru/)

https://prnt.sc/l1uext - скрин нужного меню.

Я попытался реализовать такое на пример слайдера, решением slick, но у меня не получается сделать прокрутку слайдов в зависимость от силы свайпа, то есть:

Если человек мышкой или пальцом свайпнул не сильно, то промоталось к примеру 3-4 слайда, если свайпнул сильнее, то 7-9 слайдов.
Как такое можно реализовать?